# unable to get to one value from multiple values json python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

working on a project and this is driving me nuts , I have search online and found few answer that have work for my other queries that are json related however for this one its a bit of nightmare keep getting TrackStack error

this is my json

```
ServerReturnJson = {
    "personId":"59c16cab-9f28-454e-8c7c-213ac6711dfc",
    "persistedFaceIds":["3aaafe27-9013-40ae-8e2a-5803dad90d04"],
    "name":"ramsey,",
    "userData":null
}

data = responseIdentify.read()
print("The following data return :  " + data)

#Parse json data to print just 

load = json.loads(data)

print(load[0]['name'])
```

and thats where my problem is I am unable to get the value form name , try for next statement and then i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python-Windows\random_test\cogT2.py", line 110, in <module>
    for b in load[0]['name']:
KeyError: 0
```

using this for loop

```
for b in load[0]['name']:
   print b[load]
```

any support would be most welcome am sure its something simple just can not figure it out.

Comment: The data you show is not a list and thus will not have a `0` index.  You do not show what you want to get, and I see no reason for a `for` loop at all.

Comment: what's the output of print("The following data return :  " + data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding how to reference nested dicts and lists in JSON is the hardest part.  Here's a few things to consider.

## Using your original data

```
ServerReturnJson = {
    "personId":"59c16cab-9f28-454e-8c7c-213ac6711dfc",
    "persistedFaceIds":["3aaafe27-9013-40ae-8e2a-5803dad90d04"],
    "name":"ramsey,",
    "userData":'null'
}

# No index here, just the dictionary key
print(ServerReturnJson['name'])
```

## Added second person  by making a list of dicts

```
ServerReturnJson = [{
    "personId":"59c16cab-9f28-454e-8c7c-213ac6711dfc",
    "persistedFaceIds":["3aaafe27-9013-40ae-8e2a-5803dad90d04"],
    "name":"ramsey",
    "userData": 'null'
},
    {
        "personId": "234123412341234234",
        "persistedFaceIds": ["1241234123423"],
        "name": "miller",
        "userData": 'null'
    }
]

# You can use the index here since you have a list of dictionaries
print(ServerReturnJson[1]['name'])

# You can iterate like this
for item in ServerReturnJson:
    print(item['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support basically Microsoft Face API is returning back json with no index like Chris said in this first example

The above example works only if you add the following
     data = responseIdentify.read() #  read incoming respond form server
     ServerReturnJson = json.loads(data)

so the complete answer is as follows :

```
dataJson= {
    "personId":"59c16cab-9f28-454e-8c7c-213ac6711dfc",
    "persistedFaceIds":["3aaafe27-9013-40ae-8e2a-5803dad90d04"],
    "name":"ramsey,",
    "userData":'null'
    }
    # add json load here 
    ServerReturnJson = json.loads(dataJson)
    # No index here, just the dictionary key
    print(ServerReturnJson['name'])
```

credits to Chris thanks , one last thing Chris mention  "Understanding how to reference nested dicts and lists in JSON is the hardest part" 100% agreed